# ReactNative Scrollview.onScrollEndDrag velocity.x means

Tags: react-native, scrollview

When we subscribe `ScrollView.onScrollEndDrag` it gives us `nativeEvent`. Which has velocity in it. The following shows how it's defined in typescript.

```
export interface NativeScrollEvent {
    contentInset: NativeScrollRectangle;
    contentOffset: NativeScrollPoint;
    contentSize: NativeScrollSize;
    layoutMeasurement: NativeScrollSize;
    velocity?: NativeScrollVelocity;
    zoomScale: number;
    /**
     * @platform ios
     */
    targetContentOffset?: NativeScrollPoint;
}
```

In velocity, we have x and y velocity as a number which is a negative or positive number as it decreases or increases.
I want to know what does that 1 exactly means like 1 pixel per second or ...